# Create a site-column of type user, multichoice and multiuser using Sharepoint Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, site-column, custom-field-types

I'm trying to create site-columns with following types:
**Text, Note, Number, Choice, User, MultiUser, MultiChoice**

I've implemented it for all the types except for **User, MultiChoice and MultiUser.** Can't seem to find how to achieve it. This is what I've achieved so far.

```
StringBuilder choiceFieldGenericShema = new StringBuilder();
                    choiceFieldGenericShema.Append("<Field Type='Choice' Format='Dropdown' Group='{1}' Name='{0}' DisplayName='{2}' Status='{3}' > <CHOICES> ");
                    choiceFieldGenericShema.Append("</CHOICES>  </Field> ");
                    string choicFieldSchema = string.Format(choiceFieldGenericShema.ToString(), columnItem.Title, columnItem.GroupName, columnItem.Name, columnItem.Status);
                    var newField = web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(choicFieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
                    clientContext.Load(newField);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Can anyone please suggest a way following the above method to achieve my task? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

i have used below code for multichoice and choice site columns.

```
string choiceFieldListOfValues = "A;B;C";
                string[] optionSetArray = choiceFieldListOfValues.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                StringBuilder choiceFieldGenericShema = new StringBuilder();
                if (spColumnType == "Choice")
                {
                    choiceFieldGenericShema.Append("<Field Group='{3}' Name='{0}' DisplayName='{1}' Type='{2}' " + strValue + " > <CHOICES> ");
                }
                else if (spColumnType == "MultiChoice")
                {
                    choiceFieldGenericShema.Append("<Field Group='{3}' Name='{0}' DisplayName='{1}' Type='{2}' > <CHOICES> ");
                }
                foreach (string optionValue in optionSetArray)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionValue))
                    {
                        choiceFieldGenericShema.Append("<CHOICE>" + optionValue.Trim() + "</CHOICE> ");
                    }
                }
                choiceFieldGenericShema.Append("</CHOICES>  </Field> ");
                columnGenericSchema = choiceFieldGenericShema.ToString();
                string columnSchema = string.Format(columnGenericSchema, spColumn[0], spColumn[0], spColumnType, ConfigurationConstants.SharepointSiteColumsGroupName);
                var newField = rootWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(columnSchema, true, SP.AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to know the XML of a filed is to create the field from UI first, then use a tool like [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/), to check the Xml Schema of the field. The issue in your Choice field is that, you haven't defined any choice options and second you have defined a property named `Status` which I don't think is a valid property. Here is a sample xml of a choice field:

```
<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="Colors" Required="FALSE" Format="Dropdown" FillInChoice="FALSE" Name="Colors">
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>Red</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>Green</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>Blue</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
</Field>
```